# Command to paste a value from DOB instead of manually doing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to pull each month from the DOB in my excel sheet and I was wondering if there's a specific command to pull each customers month and input it into a separate cell instead of having to manually do it each time for each customer.

DOBs

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MONTH function does exactly what you'd expect. [Here's some examples](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-month-function), along with [a more advanced take](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-month-name-from-date).

Comment: Thank you, worked

Comment: @Decjk No problem. If you're happy with it, then tick the big checkmark to accept the answer once you've got a chance.